# How do you cast a string representing a Lambda Expression to an System.LINQ.Expressions.Expression

Tags: lambda, c#-4.0

I have a class with a property of type `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` and I want to set this property with a string like `"m => m.A + m.B = m.C"`.

If I write this as new `Type<T>(){propertyName = m => m.A + m.B = m.C}` sets this property to a `true` return.

I want to be able to do this:

```
string s = "m => m.A + m.B = m.C";
Type<T> t = new Type<T>(){propertyName = s}

if(t.propertyName){//do something}
```

I have a collection of strings representing these anonymous methods and wish to tests these dynamically based on selectable criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The following link has information about dynamic linq querying. Perhaps reflection over their DLLs might help out.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Ultimately you will need to use the static factory methods on System.Linq.Expressions.Expression to build the expression.

I make 2 assumptions here:

- You really want string s = m.A + m.B
- A and B are both properties and not fields

Here is a test class to illustrate my example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a static class and method that would build the lambda expression, convert to Expression<Func<TestClass, string>>, then compile it to a Func<TestClass, string> that you can run just as any method call.

```
public static class TestHelper
{
    public static string GetString()
    {
        var testObject = new TestClass { A = "Hey", B = "Man" }; //Replace TestClass
        var type = testObject.GetType();
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "m");
        var property1 = Expression.Property(parameter, "A");
        var property2 = Expression.Property(parameter, "B");
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
        var concat = Expression.Call(mi, property1, property2);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TestClass, string>>(concat, parameter); //Replace TestClass

        var newFunction = lambda.Compile();
        string s = newFunction(testObject); //Replace TestClass
    }
}
```